# "Заступить на работу", если тон повествования немного иронический, можно?

Tags: выбор-слов

"А в 2002 году здесь заступили на работу два премилых повара, которые, впрочем, сохранили традицию".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, вполне подходит, если они сменили других поваров, работавших там раньше.

[Толковый словарь Ожегова:](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/65886)
Заступить
Сменив кого-н., приступить к работе (разг.). З. на пост. З. на вахту. З. на ночное дежурство. Постовой только что заступил.

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что "**заступить**" в обычном смысле слова можно только *сменив* кого-то (на работе, на вахте, на посту) в порядке очереди или регламента (как правило, такой порядок распространяется на короткий промежуток времени - например, на день). В исключительном случае можно стать первым в ряду периодически сменяемых работников/служащих. Поэтому в ироническом смысле так можно говорить разве что о месте работы, которое (возможно даже, зловещим образом) из-за какого-то подвоха неизбежно оказывается временным для всех приходящих. После предложенной фразы естественно ожидать, что по упомянутой "традиции" и эти повара долго не продержались. Если таков замысел повествования, то так написать можно, в противном случае ирония лишается опоры.

Comment: А это как прокомментируете: Заступил я на эту должность, и жили бы мы хутором на мирном положении, подобно всему народу, но вскорости в наших краях объявилась банда и присучилась наш хутор дотла разорять. [М. А. Шолохов. Председатель Реввоенсовета республики (1925)]

Comment: И еще: Вытаскивать молодых инвалидов из ПНИ к себе в дом престарелых директор Пушкарев Николай Николаевич (и в свои 76 лет не утративший громкого раблезианского обаяния), начал еще в конце восьмидесятых, заступив на хозяйство через две недели после выхода в отставку с поста начальника городского угрозыска; есть в его послужном и должность начальника городского ОБХСС. [Евгения Долгинова. Пленный дух // «Русская жизнь», 2012]

Comment: Видимо, неспокойная должность. Вряд ли предшественники с повышением уходили, но была надежда, что последним заступает.

Comment: А ещё служба и штучные должности - сущности регламетированные, про шеф-повара во главе заведения можно себе представить "заступление" (к рулю).